# Update eclipse plugin editor automatically with changes in data model

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am using a table viewer in editor for my eclipse plugin. I want to know how can I set a listener on column viewers which can update automatically when there is a change in underlying data model.

Data model is shared with another view in which I am making some changes and I want the editor to reflect the changes with changes in data model.

Answer (score 0):

It should do it by default. Unless...

You didn't forget to implement your setters like this, had you?

```
public void setSome(String some) {
    propertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange("some", this.some, some);
    this.some = some;
}
```